# How to make array of curved numbers?

Tags: java, javascript, math

I need to make a function that returns an array of ascending numbers, that if we draw visually, should look curved like this:

[image]

Example of expected result: `0, 110, 650, 1500, 2800, 4800, 7300, 10500, 14500, 19200, ...`

I honestly don't know how to achieve this, please give a hint or a piece of code, or help by providing me with the exact terms to search (if it's a math thing?), I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: An exponential function? For example: `e^x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Math.Exp(base, exponent)` I believe it has what you're looking for.  To influence the curve, try adding more terms with coefficients.

ex:

```
int[] curve = new int[400];
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
{
    curve[i]= Math.Exp(i,2) + (4*i);  // y=(x^2)+4i
}
```

You may need a cast in there to convert the Double that Math.Exp() spits out to int (or whatever you prefer).

Comment: `To influence the cruve add more terms with coefficients` do you mean the (4*i) part ?

Comment: @Reacen yes.  You can adjust the sharpness of the curve by changing the exponent, too.

Comment: Do you think it's possible I can produce the exact numbers: `0, 110, 650, 1500, 2800, ...` by tweaking these exponent numbers (the 2, and the 4*i) ?

Comment: @Reacen What you're looking for is called an Exponential Regression.  It allows you to find a function (which you can turn to code) for a given set of points.  Search it on Math.StackExchange and you'll get tons of results.  You can also make a graphing calculator do all the work for you.  See: [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-an-Exponential-Regression-Using-a-Graphing-Calculator)

Comment: I love you, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you need it to start from 0, try [Math.expm1(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#expm1%28double%29),

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  r[i] = Math.expm1((double)i);
}
...
```